# combining three list into one list

Tags: python, list

Here is my code to combine the three lists.

```py
one=['nlo_90', 'nhi_76', 'nhi_88']
two=['12', '44', '84']
three=[['a','a','b','c'], ['g','a','g','g'], ['b','g','g','b']]
new_three=[list(dict.fromkeys(q)) for q in three]

z=zip(one,two,new_three)
for a,b,c in z:
    print(f'a:{a},\tb:{b},\tc:{c}')
```

Below is the output:

```
a:nlo_90,   b:12,   c:['a', 'b', 'c']
a:nhi_76,   b:44,   c:['g', 'a']
a:nhi_88,   b:84,   c:['b', 'g']
```

My desired output is:

```
a:nlo_90,   b:12,   c:a, b, c
a:nhi_76,   b:44,   c:g, a
a:nhi_88,   b:84,   c:b, g
```

Comment: ``", ".join(c)`` ?

Comment: Not what you asked for, but consider using `set` instead of your dict method for removing duplicates from `three`. `new_three = [set(q) for q in three]`.

Comment: Building strings from component parts is available from any tutorial on strings.  We expect you to do basic research before posting here.  Where did you get stuck with those materials?

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the list into a joined string with `', '` as the internal separator. Currently, it's printing the full list: `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Using `', '.join(c)` will take each item in the list, and put the `', '` between them as a combined string. Since your items are strings, there isn't any conversion during the combining, so final output is: `a, b, c`.

```py
for a, b, c in z:
    c_str = ', '.join(c)
    print(f'a:{a},\tb:{b},\tc:{c_str}')
```